# Control-M Swagger UI API: Is there any API to fetch the history of a job?

Tags: control-m

`/run/jobs/status` allows us to get the current status of a job or multiple jobs such as job end time, run status and so on.
My question is, is there any API to get the run history of a job? Through an API I'd like to see a job's run history (For example: Job A ended OK on the 1st October, Job A ended Not OK on the 30th September and so on..)

I have explored all available APIs on the Control-M Swagger UI but wasn't able to find one that outputs the job history.